# Display self references in template

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm pretty new in Django...
My question : how can I get the "self foreign key" name in a template via a listView ?
Thanks...

**models.py**

```
class Organization(Model.models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mother_organization = models.ForeignKey('self',
                                            null=True,
                                            blank=True,
                                            related_name='mother'
                                            )
```

**views.py**

```
class List(ListView):
    model = Organization
    context_object_name = "organizations"
    template_name = "organizations.html"
```

**organizations.html**

```
{% for organization in organizations %}
    <p>
        {{ organization.reference }}
        {{ organization.name }}
        test 0 : OK !!
        {{ organization.mother_organization.name|default:"-" }}
        test 1 : FAIL
        {{ organization.mother.name|default:"-" }}
        test 2 : FAIL
        {% for mother in organization.mother.all %}
            {{ mother.name }}
        {% empty %}
        test 3 : FAIL
        {% for mother in organization.mother_organization.all %}
            {{ mother.name }}
        {% empty %}

            #
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field name is `mother_organization`, so you should use the same field name in your template:

```
{{ organization.mother_organization.name|default:"-" }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but already tested (but not mentionned -> new edit) and didn't work... sorry

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? What error do you have?

Comment: The template returns the default value ("-"). In the admin page, everything is OK !

Comment: Do you get object `organizations` object in template? In other words, doe your for loop actually loop through a list of `organizations`?

Comment: Absolutely, the for loop returns all "my" companies ;-) !

Comment: I don' think I could find anything else at this point. Maybe only use `{{ organization.mother_organization }}` to see if it shows anything, also make sure the `mother_organization` is not empty.

Comment: It is not empty. I filled a few organizations and some with a "mother". And the admin page displays the mother column, filled correctly !

Comment: OK... I felle very bad today... Solution #0 worked... Grrrr. I don't understand. I'm very sorry. So sure, your solution is valid.

Comment: No worries. Django template is not a good tool for debugging so invalid variables will simply be treated as empty. Just back off a little and go back later when you stuck usually solves the problem.

Comment: Absolutely ! I think I found out why my pb was. My _Organization_ model actually derived from another model : _Customer_. So in the template, I have to point to **customer.organization.mother_compoany**. Thanks for all.